# new controller creation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

So while learning Laravel 5, I've experienced the following problem.

I've created the new controller named **ContactController** in the folder:
*app/Http/Controllers/Pages/ContactController.php*
and I have the following code in it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Pages;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return 'This is the Contact page.';
    }

    public function getMyDetails() {
        return 'This is the My Details page.';
    }
}
```

and I also added the following code into my **web routes**:
*routes/web.php*

```
Route::resource('contact', 'Pages\ContactController');
```

According to what I understood, it should automatically show me the message *"This is the My Details page."* when I open the URL address: http://laravel.devpeaks.com/public/contact/my-details. Instead I get the error:
BadMethodCallException in compiled.php line 6271:
Method controller does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) do not work like that. `Route::resource` will create 7 CRUD routes for you: `index`, `show`, `create`, `store`, `edit`, `update`, `delete`

If you want to add `my-details` route, add this to `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('contact/my-details', 'Pages\ContactController@getMyDetails');
```

Comment: Well, now you should win. :)

Comment: In order to avoid creating every-single route manually via ::get, I thought it's possible via typing it once, Laravel can automatically create all other methods as routes? This is what I understood from tutorials today. Is it true? :) Like it will get "getMyDetails" from the method name and interpeter it as the URL "/my-details".

Comment: No, it's not possible without `controller()` which was deprecated and removed. It seems you're reading some pretty old tutorial.